# Confused about adding two numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, sum, arm, output, user-input

I'm new to assembly language and am working on an assignment where I must ask the user to input three numbers and then my program needs to add them up and display the value to them. I was trying to work off of my professor's sample code but I keep getting an error on line 9 preventing me from running the code. I added **add %r, %d,%d** on line 43 to store in the sum for %r at line 9 but I guess I'm doing something wrong?

```
.section .data
/* Prompt message */
prompt: .asciz "Hi there! Please type in two integer values (seperated by a space): "

/* Response message */
response: .asciz "I read the numbers %d and %d from the keyboard\n" /* Line 9, this has an error */

/* Reponse message2 */
response: .asciz "Their sum is %r\n"

/* Format pattern for scanf */
pattern: .asciz "%d %d"

/* Where scanf will store the number read */
value_read1: .word 0
value_read2: .word 0

.section .text
.global main
main:
    push {lr}       /* save our return address */

    // use r4, r5 as registers holding pointers to value_read1, and value_read2
    ldr r4, =value_read1
    ldr r5, =value_read2

        ldr r0, =prompt     /* r0 contains pointer to prompt message */
        bl printf       /* call printf to output our prompt */

        ldr r0, =pattern    /* r0 contains pointer to format string for our scan pattern */
        mov r1, r4      /* r1 contains pointer to variable label where our first number is stored */
    mov r2, r5      /* r2 contains pointer to variable label where our second number is stored */
        bl scanf                /* call to scanf */
next:
    ldr r0, =response   /* r0 contains pointer to response message */
    mov r1, r4      /* r4 contains pointer to value_read1 */
    ldr r1, [r1]        /* r1 contains value dereferenced from r1 in previous instruction */
    mov r2, r5
    ldr r2, [r2]
    bl printf       /* call printf to output our response */

    add %r, %d,%d   /* Line 43 */

    mov r0, #0      /* exit code 0 = program terminated normally */
    pop {pc}        /* exit our main function */
```

Comment: Assembly language questions should always have a tag for the machine architecture being used.  I've added the [tag:arm] tag for you; please use it for future questions on this topic.

Comment: The general-purpose user registers on ARM are `r0` through `r12`, just as you see them used in the rest of the code.  I am not sure what you think `%r` and `%d` would mean.  The `%r` and `%d` in the strings are to be interpreted by the `printf` and `scanf` functions, which you could look up, and are not part of assembly language per se.

Comment: Ok thank you for adding the arm tag. %d was already in my professor's code. I added %r after trying R0 which didn't work for me. I just wanted %r to work as a value to hold the sum for the two numbers entered by the user.

Comment: The only things you can use as operands to the `add` instruction are the machine registers r0, r1, ..., or r12.  You cannot invent new variables to be used here, that is not how assembly language works.  It might be that you need to study the concepts of ARM architecture and assembly some more before starting to write code, otherwise this may not get you much of anywhere.  There's a deeper problem in that you have placed the `add` instruction where it cannot have any effect on what is printed.

Comment: It seems that for some reason, line 9 gives me an error no matter what I type. I tried changing it to: [response: .asciz "Their sum is r7\n"] and moving line 43 up before line 9 and replacing %r with r7 but I'm still getting an error for line 9. Also, I have some experience in C++ but Assembly is completely new to me.

Comment: I'm sorry to say I think it is going to be too hard to help you in the setting of Stack Overflow.  There are fundamental concepts that you seem to be missing rather badly, and SO is not a good format for teaching them, even if someone could put in the time.  I would suggest going back to your professor, studying some more basic materials, or trying simpler examples.  Trying random variations to the code without understanding is not going to succeed.